# error in struts2 project related to struts2 core jar

Tags: eclipse, struts2, eclipse-plugin

I have added all the required jars for struts project but while running the project on tomcat v8 i am getting this error

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 3: jar:file:\C:\Users\RITESH\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\StrutsLoginDemoApp\WEB-INF\lib\struts2-core-2.3.1.1.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(Unknown Source)
```

using windows 10 and struts 2.3.1.1 jars on eclipse Oxygen version. Has someone faced this issue already? I am guessing it's related to the extra ":\" that is being added in the filepath,but it it's inside the jar. How can i fix this?

Comment: What jar are you talking about? There's no references in S2 to your path or machine, so this is a build or configuration problem on your end. There's not enough information to help at this point.

Comment: Post the web.xml. It's complaining that you're using the jar protocol (the string index of 3).

Comment: thanks for the clarity. it was a configuration issue as u have suggested. Issue resolved